# react-elastic-carousel dynamic itemsToShow depending screen size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, react-elastic-carousel

I'm using react-elastic-carousel in vertical mode. Items in there have a fixed height. I would like the number of items to show to be dependend on the available space on the screen.

In my App.tsx:

```
<div className="App-body">
  <Carousel verticalMode itemsToShow={1}>
    {state.items.map((item, index) => <Item key={index}>{item.text}</Item>)}
  </Carousel>
</div>
```

https://sag1v.github.io/react-elastic-carousel/verticalMode

Item.tsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #683bb7;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 4vw;
`;
```

At this point I'm not sure how to handle this at all. Somehow the component has to get the height of its parent element, know how height the items will be and calculate a number that fits. Ofcourse this has to be done each time a screen is resized.
Any ideas?

Comment: I've had a similar issue, but item's height was a variable that would be calculated only after it renders. I ended up having an array of children's heights in the parent. When child renders it would send back it's height to a parent via a callback. Parent stores it in the array and then calculates what's needed base on this data.

Comment: sounds interesting. I can set the height or witdth of my items to fixed. But the app will be used on a variety of screen sizes. So would like this to be dynamic. Any chance you can share some of that code?

Answer (score 2):

Use breakPoints as Props in the Carousel Component:

```
 const breakPoints = [ 
   {width:1,itemsToShow:1},
   {width:500,itemsToShow:2},
   {width:768,itemsToShow:3},
   {width:1100,itemsToShow:4}
 ]
```